# Xcode is hanging whenever I try to open any file other than Storyboard?

Tags: xcode, error-handling

I recently updated my Mac software to OS X El Capitan. Xcode started crashing repeatedly! Whenever I tried to create a new file, it crashed. So, I updated it to Xcode 7. Now, whenever I create a new file, the beach ball appears and the application stops responding. I end up force quitting. This happens with every project. Whenever I click on any file, the same happens. I really need an answer to this as soon as possible because I am partly dependent on Xcode.

Comment: You should be a little more precise and not only tells "it crashed". Could you provide some more information?

Comment: update it to 7.1 !!! BTW what is the configuration of your mac ?